# sending a log with logging module get stuck

Tags: python, logging

I have two http servers that talk with each other using logging module.

```
serverA = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8888), myHandler)
serverB = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 7777), myHandler)
```

first serverA sends GET request to serverB :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('cs')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(HTTPHandler("localhost:7777", "/"))
logger.warning('log from serverA')
```

then, serverB answers with a POST msg:

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger('mach')
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(HTTPHandler("localhost:8888", "/",method='POST'))
        print "1111"
        logger.critical('POST from 7777')
        print "2222"
        return
```

while debugging it, I see that "1111" is printed out, but "2222" isn't, and that in do_POST method of serverA, the first line which is a print command - is not printed out.
However, when I inspected it with wireshark, I see a tcp packet going to port 8888 and its my POST msg..

so what can happen that I dont see it in serverA ?

Comment: You've wrote about do_POST method, but there is no this method in your code (only do_GET).

Comment: yes,, but there is a do_POST function in myHandler of serverB.
and anyway, I tryedsending a GET from B to A instead of POST - still stuck - can't see a first print in serverA.. so its not a problem with the POST

Comment: Try to send POST request via command line to test whether your HTTP server is working or not: $ curl -v -d "POST from 7777" http://localhost:8888. You should messages, which your server prints, in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deadlock between the two servers. Here's the scenario:

- Server A sends a GET request to server B and *blocks* waiting for a    response, i.e. the following does not return until a response is received (or an error occurs):

  ```
  logger.warning('log from serverA')
  ```
- Server B receives the GET request from server A in `do_GET()`, but it does not send a reply. Instead it sends a POST request back to server A, then server B *blocks* waiting for a response from server A:

  ```
  logger.critical('POST from 7777')
  ```
- Both servers are single threaded, and both are blocked waiting on a response from the other, hence a deadlock.